# Why is element.$error.email null instead of false?

Tags: angularjs

If I type in a valid email address in the textbox, `myForm.myAddress.$error.email` is `null`.

However if I type an invalid email address, `myForm.myAddress.$error.email` is `true`.

When a valid email address is inputted, why is the value `null` rather than `false`?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<form ng-app="" name="myForm">
    <input type="email" name="myAddress" ng-model="text">
    {{myForm.myAddress.$error.email}}
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I edit post with new possible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because if you have **invalid address** you will have **true** because you have an **error** myForm.myAddress.**$error**.email when is **valid** no errors and its **null**, i suppose who made this doesn't think about return false.

For fix this issue you need use `myForm.input.$valid`

[image]
[image]

**Documentation Link:** https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bemail%5D

Comment: I understand that its value is null, but my question is why? A bool is usually true or false. If there is no error wouldn't it make more sense for it to be false?

Comment: @Backwards_Dave This is because the developer who made it don't think about return **false**, i suppose.

Comment: The `$error` value of a form is not set to `true` when an error occurs but to an array of objects describing the error in more detail (`required` for example could occur more than once). Therefore `form.$error.xxx` is `null` or an array. It seems only fitting that `control.$error.xxx` is `null` or `true`.